# Getting "undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)" in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to make a 2-d array at run time using for loop.But I am getting this error "undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)" again and again and I am not getting this.I am new to ruby.Here is my code:

```
puts "Enter row count:"
row = gets.to_i
puts "Enter column count:"
col = gets.to_i
sub_arr = Array.new
arr = Array.new
puts "enter elements:"
for i in (1..row) do
    for j in (1..col) do
        sub_arr[j] = gets.chomp
        puts "sub array is: #{sub_arr}"
        arr[i].push(sub_arr)
    end
end
puts "size of array: #{arr.size}"
puts "array is: #{arr}"
```

It should look something like this: arr= [[1,"a"],[3,"b"],[5,"c"]].
Please help me to correct my mistakes.

Comment: You're trying to push a value to `arr[i]`, but there's nothing there. You don't initialize value of `arr` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is with accessing and adding values to array object inside the loop and the range you're using starts from one. But, the array index always starts from 0.

The update code is below:

```
puts "Enter row count:"
row = gets.to_i
puts "Enter column count:"
col = gets.to_i
sub_arr = Array.new
arr = Array.new
puts "enter elements:"
for i in (0...row) do
    arr[i] = arr[i] || []
    for j in (0...col) do
        arr[i][j] = gets.chop 
        puts "sub array is: #{arr}"
    end
end
puts "size of array: #{arr.size}"
puts "array is: #{arr}"
```

Ref: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html to understand how arrays work and methods supported.

Comment: Thanku so much for this code.This is exactly what I want but I didn't understand what and how "arr[i] = arr[i] || []" this line is doing. Can you please explain?

Comment: Basically you need 2D array to add the inputs to array. This 'arr = Array.new' creates an 1D array object and this 'arr[i] = arr[i] || []' checks if the array is already having second dimension for row and assigns row to arr if it is not present.

Answer (score 1):

You're initialising an empty array in 'arr' and attempting to push to the empty arr object by an index that does not exist with 'arr[i].' This accessor will always return 'nil' and you're attempting to call push on nil object.

From what I can tell, an array of hashes seems more suitable a data object for your purpose than a two dimensional array, based purely on how you're treating the hashes. There may be some duplicate keys, but you can append to the values.

From the code snippet, you'll need to do the following to make your approach with 2 dimensional arrays work:

```
# inside loop
arr[i] = [sub_arr]
```

But I'm unsure what inputs you're expecting and there does seem to be room for overwriting existing data with this approach. This will initialise a new array if the index is not found and override the array at the index if it exists.